# Parallel multiplication of large integers

Tags: algorithm

What is the best algorithm to perform parallel multiplication of large integers?

Comment: Is that really your bottleneck?

Comment: Maybe this question is better suited to "programmers" forum.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best choice is using [Fast Fourier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Fourier_transform_methods) multiplication. you can use [parallel algorithms for calculating FFT](http://www.fftw.org/parallel/parallel-fftw.html) and its reverse, also adding elements can be parallelise.